# RestKit for persisting certain objects but not others

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, restkit

I'm using RestKit to map remote objects into model objects. I want to add functionality which allows objects that the user picks to be persisted locally to Core Data (think a "favourites" list).

However, RestKit's Core Data support seems to be all-or-nothing, in the sense that either I stick with NSObject-derived model objects; alternatively, I use NSManagedObjects, and everything of that type that RestKit retrieves goes into the database.

Is there a way I can have RestKit map into Core Data objects, but not necessarily persist them all to the database as they come over the wire -- only selected ones?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. The map will only map attributes specified. If you favorites is a local property then don't map it in the web response and you will be fine. You may want to see the RKDynamicObjectMapping class if you have to create conditional maps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's not that 'favourites' is in the response and I don't want to map it. I want to use RestKit to map remote data to Core Data model objects, however, if I use `RKManagedObjectStore`, every instance is inserted into the database as RestKit performs the mapping. I only want particular instances inserted into the database.

Comment: So use RKDynamicObjectMapping

Comment: `RKDynamicObjectMapping` is for mapping different responses to different model objects. I want all responses mapped into model objects, but I don't want model objects automatically inserted into the database.

Comment: From what I understand, if( something ) [save in database] else [don't save] is what you want? So use the dynamic mapping to return the mapping based on your persistent class if something is true, otherwise return an empty mapping.